# How to stop infinite loop programatically?

Tags: java

Here we are taking a java program as a input to the another java program.In case if the given program contains any infinite loop then I want to kill that particular process of a input program.

```
public String javaProgram(String strFilePath, String filename) throws Exception {
        String path = strFilePath;
        String fname = filename;
        String output = "";
        String totalPath = "javac" + " " + strFilePath + "/" + fname + ".java";
        System.out.println("Total path" + totalPath);
        String s = null;
        String log = "";
        String errorfile = strFilePath + "/" + fname + "_Error.txt";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(errorfile, true);
            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(totalPath);
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getErrorStream()));
            boolean error = false;
            log += "\n....\n";
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                error = true;
                fos.write(s.getBytes());
                return "errortrue";

            }
            fos.close();
            if (error == false) {
                output = runProcess(path, fname);
                return output;
            }
            if (output.equals("success")) {
                return "sucess";

            } else {
                return "false";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    private static String runProcess(String command, String filename) throws Exception {
        String path1 = "java" + " " + "-cp" + " " + command + "/" + " " + filename;
        System.out.println("Path" + path1);
        String filepath = command + "/" + filename + "_output.txt";
        System.out.println("filepath=============" + filepath);

        System.out.println("Entered");

        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path1);

        String s = printLines(filepath, pro.getInputStream());
        return s;
    }

    private static String printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line = null;
        int count=0;
        String strFilePath = name;
        System.out.println("NAME" + name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath, false);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            fos.write(line.getBytes());
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
//            count++;
//            if(count>10){
//                break;
//            }
        }



        fos.close();

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: How do you know if a loop is infinite or just a long running one?

Comment: i don't think  a normal program you can halt like that!    in multi-threaded program you may do it by checking timeout tends to few minutes.

Comment: Actually here we are trying to execute very basic java programs. So its execution may not take more time. If the execution time exceeds 5 seconds, then I'm assuming that it contains infinite loop. It doesn't mean it should contain infinite loop.

Comment: Put your `runProcess` into a thread and start a timer. If the timer hits 5s, close the other thread.

Comment: I don't understand the massive downvotes. As the answers show, the halting problem is a classic computer science problem. Not unreasonable for someone to bump into.

Answer (score 3):

There's a well known problem in computer science called the *halting problem*. There's a lot of fancy math and interesting discussion involved, but the part that matters for you is that it has been proven that it is impossible to detect in general whether or not a program will run forever. There are specific cases that can be found statically, such as `while (true)`, but if your goal is to have a robust supervisor that can kill an infinite running program, you're going to have difficulties.

*Instead*, I would recommend that you take the approach of implementing a time-out. Give the program an amount of time within which it can run. If it takes more than that, kill it. For example, if you decide 10 minutes is too long, kill any program that takes longer than 10 minutes. This should happen to be much more practical.

Comment: That's what we are trying to do but we are unable to stop the execution of that program after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It has been proven almost a century ago, that it is generally undecidable whether a given program will halt (and therefore does not contain an infinite loop).

Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem.